# Angular UI-Routing, Page automatically redirects to parent state when refreshed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a project in which I have used Angular-UI routing. When I try to refresh web page or enter URL directly, It is redirected to parent state. It does load the state of the URL which I have reloaded but then quickly redirects to parent state. Here is my state routing

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "home": {
                templateUrl: root_url + "home"
                },
            },
        })
    .state('home.store', {
        url: "/store",
        views: {
            "store": {
                templateUrl: root_url + "store"
                },
            },
        })
    .state('home.store.storecontent', {
        views: {
            "storecontent": {
                templateUrl: root_url + "storecontent"
                }
            }
        })
```

Suppose currently I am on home.store.storecontent state. If I refreshed the page here, after reloading current state, It redirects me to the parent state which is home. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Maybe add an URL to `home.store.storecontent`?

Comment: I tried the same before posting the question. Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Without an URL, you cannot refresh a state. I would also change your "home" URL to "/"

Answer (score 3):

We have two options in general. First is to define **url** for child, the second is - make parent abstract which will mean that it child is default.

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1ObAYF6e2XL00n0AGqq?p=preview) for first approach

In case we would like to keep parent 'home.store' and child 'home.store.storecontent' non-abstract, we have to define unique url for both of them, e.g.:

```
.state('home.store', {
    url: "/store",
    ...
    })
.state('home.store.storecontent', {
    url: "/content",
    ...
    })
```

So, now we have two links:

```
<a href="#/store">
<a href="#/store/content">
```

And each of them will on refresh have **unique target**. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1ObAYF6e2XL00n0AGqq?p=preview)

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K0vlVzJOhvYxpWSvfDLN?p=preview) for second approach

In case, that we want *UI-Router* to navigate to a child of 'home.store' state, we just have to make it **abstract**. Then - if there is a *child* with `url: ""` - it will be used as a non abstract state to be initiated.

These adjustment should do that:

```
.state('home.store', {
    url: "/store",
    // here, we make home.store to be abstract
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "store": {
            templateUrl: root_url + "store"
            },
        },
    })
.state('home.store.storecontent', {
    // here, we say, that instead of parent (which url is selected)
    // this child state should be initiated
    url: "",
    views: {
        "storecontent": {
            templateUrl: root_url + "storecontent"
            }
        }
    })
```

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/K0vlVzJOhvYxpWSvfDLN?p=preview)

In case, that the **'home.store'** should not be abstract, we should give some non empty *url* to its child - to distinguish these two...

Comment: I don't want to make home.store abstract. I want to avoid redirection to parent state when I refresh some page which contains child state.

Comment: The problem is, that child does not have URL defined. That means, that if you refresh - browser is starting from the beginning. It must init UI-Router, pass the URL. UI-Router will find out.. ahaaa... it is #/store... and it means 'home.store' - and will init it. So as I pointed out you have two options 1) make parent abstract - child will be directly selected 2) define unique url for child...

Comment: I extended my answer and showed both approaches. Hope it hleps ;) Enjoy the UI-Router

Comment: I have defined unique URL for each state. Still it is not working. When I defined root state (which is home) as abstract, Home page itself doesn't get loaded. When I looked at network calls, all the AJAX calls and the HTML template of the current state are loaded. After this, page is redirected to parent state.

Comment: Look, I did my best, to create few WORKING plunkers for you. They do follow your solution and DO work. I suggest.. compare them. Try to change them to be as yours.. and it will reveal what is wrong... hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

are you using md-tabs with ui-sref and md-active?

if you are, the problem is that md-active fire click on tab, then you are redirected to the parent state.

i was with this problem and it is solved right now with https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5351

Answer (score 0):

On each state change success event you need to cache or store in localStorage the current state name and when you refresh you can load from it if the login is valid.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {//You can save your storing state name function here}
```