# angularjs, in a page when we press F5 key or browser refresh again it's not getting to that page instead going to home page always

Tags: angularjs

In our java web application...
We are using `angular js 1.4`. 
`$stateProvider` for `routing` .
We have child view inside a parent view.

When we click on browser refresh in any page, whole application getting refreshed and loading from first then it is always redirected to home page instead of that page.

What I want is when we click on F5 or browser refresh in any page it has to redirect to that same page.

I tried with `$stateChangeStart`,`$locationChangeStart`
`$window.onbeforeload` but nothing worked for me.
I don't know why from root it's getting reload

this is parent state

```
$stateProvider.state('homeView', {
    url : '/home',
    templateUrl : './home.html',
    controller : 'AppController',
    data : {
        requireLogin : true
    }
});
```

every controller we are reffering parent like this

```
$stateProvider.state('detailsview', {
    url : '/details/:divId',
    parent : 'homeView',
    templateUrl : './details/details.html',
    params : {
        'searchCriteria' : null
    },
    controller : 'CoreMarginDetailsController',
    data : {
        requireLogin : true
    }
});
```

for state transition we are calling a particular state.

```
$state.go('detailsview', {
                'searchCriteria' : $scope.searchCriteriaData
            });
```

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101681/angular-ui-routing-page-automatically-redirects-to-parent-state-when-refreshed?rq=1

Comment: hi santhosh i added my stateProvider code any info needed ?